# Route do not been cleaned when unmountOnBlur

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, navigation-drawer, react-navigation-v5

I have an application that pass an order from the screen 1 as a param utilizing this.props.navigation.navigate('Screen',{order}) to the screen 2 and do some stuff in the screen 2. Then I navigate to another screen using the Drawer side menu. When I come back to the screen 2 utilizing the drawer menu the order still in the param (the route was not reseted).
I'm using class Component in my project and when I tried to put something like a reset in the componentWillUnmount, but the react native don't let me do that because this would be a asyncronous call.

In my order class I did (Screen 2):

```
componentWillUnmout() {
  // some code
  
  this.props.navigation.reset();
}
```

In the Screen 1 I did:

```
  this.props.navigation.navigate('Screen 2', {order});
```

I tried do what was decribed in this question: https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/6915 but I had no sucess.

How could I reset this params in this conditions? Could I made a listener to reset the route when a navigate to another page in the Drawer Menu?

Comment: I was able to solve the problem by cleaning the params after reciving it in the page. It's not what I was tring to do but it worked.

Answer (score 0):

If your second page is an order details, you better use the stack pile of screens by pushing a new one.

```
this.props.navigation.push('orderDetails', {order});
```

Like that, you push a screen at the top of the stack. Navigate function search in your route history and if the screen was already open previously, it came back to it.